# rpy2 installation on macbook on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook

Trying to install `rpy2` modules on terminal and there is no action.

Trying to directly install `rpy2` on cell

```
!pip install rpy2
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
%%R -i data 
data <- list('0.47', '-0.36', '-0.5', '0.2', '0.35', '1.82', 
             '-0.78', '-0.91', '0.36', '-1.74', '0.24', '0.76', 
             '0.57', '2.32', '1.55', '-1.31', '-0.09', '-0.02', 
             '-0.07', '-0.19', '-0.25', 
             '-1.09', '0.64', '1.22', '-0.56', '1.76', '0.13', 
             '1.33', '-0.74', '-1.15', '1.63', '1.04', '-0.26', 
             '0.02', '-1.2', '0.37', '0.43', '0.04', '1.34', 
             '0.57', '0.76', '-1.25', '-0.05', '0.12', '0.8', 
             '-0.99', '-0.11', '-0.54', '-0.08', '-0.04', '-0.76', 
             '-0.8', '0.35', '1.54', '-0.99', '-0.35', '-0.28', '0.45', 
             '-0.04', '-0.06', '0.02', '0.58', '-0.32', '-0.1', '0.28', 
             '0.3', '-0.36', '0.81', '0.79', '0.21', '1.81', '0.19', '0.84', 
             '0.2', '-0.06', '-0.11', '-1.4', '-2.08', '0.88', '-0.14',
             '-0.96', '1.3', '0.06', '-0.37', '1.49', '-0.91', 
             '1.14', '-1.05', '1.49', '-0.79', '2.02', '0.38', '2.4', '1.25', 
             '0.5', '1.11', '-0.54', '-0.1', '0.63', '1.01')
num <- as.numeric(unlist(data))
shapiro.test(num)
shapiro.test
```

The results show

```
 File "<ipython-input-3-0be657748cce>", line 20
    num <- as.numeric(unlist(data))
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It still doesn't work

I just wanna the R code to be attached on my Jupyter notebook.

```
data <- list('0.47', '-0.36', '-0.5', '0.2', '0.35', '1.82', 
             '-0.78', '-0.91', '0.36', '-1.74', '0.24', '0.76', 
             '0.57', '2.32', '1.55', '-1.31', '-0.09', '-0.02', 
             '-0.07', '-0.19', '-0.25', 
             '-1.09', '0.64', '1.22', '-0.56', '1.76', '0.13', 
             '1.33', '-0.74', '-1.15', '1.63', '1.04', '-0.26', 
             '0.02', '-1.2', '0.37', '0.43', '0.04', '1.34', 
             '0.57', '0.76', '-1.25', '-0.05', '0.12', '0.8', 
             '-0.99', '-0.11', '-0.54', '-0.08', '-0.04', '-0.76', 
             '-0.8', '0.35', '1.54', '-0.99', '-0.35', '-0.28', '0.45', 
             '-0.04', '-0.06', '0.02', '0.58', '-0.32', '-0.1', '0.28', 
             '0.3', '-0.36', '0.81', '0.79', '0.21', '1.81', '0.19', '0.84', 
             '0.2', '-0.06', '-0.11', '-1.4', '-2.08', '0.88', '-0.14',
             '-0.96', '1.3', '0.06', '-0.37', '1.49', '-0.91', 
             '1.14', '-1.05', '1.49', '-0.79', '2.02', '0.38', '2.4', '1.25', 
             '0.5', '1.11', '-0.54', '-0.1', '0.63', '1.01')
num <- as.numeric(unlist(data))
shapiro.test(num)
shapiro.test
```

Comment: In your notebook, create new cell and run the `!pip install rpy2` it will install the package and you will not have to use conda. I have faced this kind of issue with conda.

Comment: This terminal window is only for outputting stuff but not for inputs. If you do not see a promt (Line starting with >, $, [], etc.), you can expect that this is only for viewing messages.

Comment: @danlooo Big hanks!

Comment: I tried install in the cell, and there is still a problem. Can anyone help? BTW, I have rewritten my question. Feel free to check it

Comment: @RopaliMunshi Retried, but still problems :(

Comment: Do you really want to set up a polyglot notebook system with R and python environments just to read a vector of numbers? Export the data in R with `readr::write_lines` and read the file in python using `[float(x) for x in open("foo.txt", "r").readlines()]`. It is much simpler. Jupyter is not designed to work easily with multiple languages and languages are designed to read from just text files.

Comment: I do @danlooo. I have been really struggling :( I don't understand why the above doesn't work :(

Comment: I do not see a single line of python in your example. Why do you need python? I want to create a simpler system for you...

Comment: @danlooo Actually, I am doing my assignment lol. Just came up with the idea if it is possible mix R and Python code. And some guys say it is ok

Comment: Please tell me the python functions you want to use. Mixing languages is a non trivial thing. BTW: `rpy2` requires you to install R as well. And this must be reachable within the juptyter kernel.

Comment: @ danlooo. Thank you so much :P You are so nice :) I do install R lmao. I think I probably should give up. Honestly, I don't know exactly python code. I just wanna the R code I wrote to be uploaded on python. I will attach my R code

Comment: You need to write  `%%R -o data data <- list(1,2,3)` instead of `-i`, because data ia a R output. You can also use just R in jupyter using [IRkernel](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel). Why are you forced to use python?

Comment: Still, I cannot get what I want. I am nearly going to give up lol. Maybe you answer the question (rewrite my code a little bit) and I give your credit? @danlooo. Much appreciated for your time

Comment: Do you really need to use python or jupyter? If you have just R code and you want to create a documentation with text between the cells, RMarkdown within RStudio will give you the easiest solution.

Comment: yes. I am only allowed to upload the ```ipynb``` file

Comment: OK. Then i'd opt for option 3 in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is showing just R code without any python functions used.

### Option 1 (easy, without jupyter and python)

If you really do not need Jupyter and python, you can just create documents with R code cells and text in between using RMarkdon inside RStudio.

### Option 2 (hard, with jupyter and python)

1. install R and python
2. install Jupyter
3. install rpy2 using `! pip install rpy2` inside a jupyter cell
4. Run R code within the notebook:

```
import rpy2
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
%%R -o data 
data <- list(1,2,3)
```

### Option 3 (medium, with jupyter using just R without python)

1. install jupyter
2. install [IRkernel](https://irkernel.github.io/)
3. start juypter and choose the R kernel
4. write just R code in your jupyter cells:

[image]

Comment: what does ```data <- list(1,2,3)``` mean? How can I transform my ```data``` above into the form you proposed

Comment: This is a placeholder with any R code. Just replace it with `data <- list('0.47', '...` instead

Comment: what does this mean? data has already been in the form ```data <- list('0.47', '...```

Comment: I've added a screenshoot

Comment: how could u run it? Using kernel R? I got it